# How to insert extra item to template each

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have such template

```
<tbody>
  {{#each topics as |topic|}}
    {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I want to insert extra item into this rendering template list, something like this:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each topics as |topic|}}
    {{#if someCondition}}
      {{my-list-item}}
    {{else}}
      {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

But the problem is this solution will skip some `topic` when `someCondition` is true, ie it will note insert but replace.

Is there a solution to add an item to template render list?

UPDATE: I want to insert `{{my-list-item}}` only once into render list if `someCondition` is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dislay topic-list-item all the time irrespective of condition then, you can do it by removing else.

```
<tbody>
      {{#each topics as |topic|}}
        {{#if someCondition}}
          {{my-list-item}}
        {{/if}}
        {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}        
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: It will insert `my-list-item` topics' size times, please see the update

Comment: `someCondition` - depends on `topic` or some other variable.  so you are saying `someCondition` will be true for many topic but `my-list-item` component should be included only one time

Comment: Maybe there should be no condition at all, just insert extra item

Comment: `my-list-item` - is this should come in top of the `topic-list-item` - then you can remove `my-list-item` from each block..otherwise one more approach would be `{{#each topics as |topic index|}}` so you can check index using ember-truth-helper like {{#if (eq index 0)}} {{my-list-item}} {{/if}}`

Answer (score 1):

I voted up the previous answer, but would like to add another common use-case:

If you don't mind extending `topic-list-item` object by additional property (in other words, if the additional template depends on any property of the `topic-list-item`), this would work:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each topics as |topic|}}
    {{#if topic.someBooleanProperty}}
      {{my-list-item}}
    {{/if}}
      {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

or (same as the answer above, just different structure)

```
  {{#each topics as |topic|}}
    {{#if topic.someBooleanProperty}}
      {{my-list-item}}
      {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}
    {{else}}
      {{topic-list-item topic=topic}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Extending object will sure work but fixing template looks much more easier.

Comment: Oh, I also see you have updated the question. In such a case my answer is not valid anymore.